# Angular2 bind string array to reactive formgroup with *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

this is my data structure

```
class myObject
{
    name: string;
    notes: string[];
}
```

I'm aiming to create a reactive form group to bind the name and all of the notes (each note have an individual control).

```
this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group
({
    name: new FormControl(getName()), //returns a string
    notes: this.formBuilder.array(getNotes()) //returns a string array
});

<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input formControlName="name">
    <div formArrayName="notes">
        <div *ngFor="let note of formGroup.controls.notes.controls; let i=index">
            <div formGroupName="{{ i }}">
                <input formControlName="{{ i }}"> // bind array element to formcontrol
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how do i bind each string in the  "property-less" string array to a formcontrol?
I'm hitting: ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'notes -> 0 -> 0'

Appreciate any help in advance!

Comment: What getNotes() returns?

Answer (score 2):

Managed to achieved the above using:

```
<div [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <input formControlName="name">
    <div formArrayName="notes">
        <div *ngFor="let note of formGroup.controls.notes.controls; let i=index">
            <div formGroupName="{{ i }}"> //remove this tag
                <input formControlName="{{ i }}">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simply remove the 'div formGroupName="{{ i }}"' tag, as it is not a nested data structure.